# Device Administration App Remotely clear data on Android Phone

Tags: android

I am creating a application in android similar to Device Policy Administration that can remotely clear the data on the Android device.I have followed the sample in the android docs here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html
I need some assistance  on how this is implemented.I have come across some apps that perform such tasks of remotely accessing the device(like clear data on the device,Ring the device to full volume).My doubt is

1.How did they implemented this functionality in android what concept have they used to  send request to the app to ring the device?Is it via Push notification?

2.Also even if i mark Settings->Security->Device administrators->Android Device Manager(ADM)->Deactivate and from the console (https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?u=0) 
I Ring the Device...the device Rings.Shouldnt it not ring until and unless i dont activate the ADM.

3.Also even if i do not launch(start) the app ,I am still able to Ring my device.Does it mean that whenever i start my device my Device Administration App gets launched automatically?

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: That's a mere combination of at least 2, if not three questions. Please consider separating them. Esp. how the requests/information is exchanged (unrelated to device management) and how the ADM rules work.

Answer (score 1):

> How did they implemented this functionality in android what concept have they used to send request to the app to ring the device?Is it via Push notification?

The Android Device Manager is a proprietary service and piece of software. You will need to get a job at Google, join the ADM team, and then learn how it is done.

That being said, a GCM-style push notification is a likely solution.

> Does it mean that whenever i start my device my Device Administration App gets launched automatically?

No. Device administration != always running. Device administration status simply gives you access to other APIs that normal apps cannot use.

Note that a GCM-style push notification can be delivered to an app that is not already running.

The rest of your question has nothing to do with programming and everything to do with the proprietary implementation of ADM, which makes it off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare.However there are some more apps that i have come across Like in QuickHeal Antivirus and AndroidLost app that has the same functionality implemented of Ringing the device or controlling other functionalities of the device.Could you please guide how to progress through.